# Is it possible to get un-minified source for redquerybuilder?

Tags: redquerybuilder

Is it possible to get un-minified source for redquerybuilder?

I like what I see but need to change quite a lot for my application.

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is free but closed source software at the moment. We are trying to understand what level of interest there is before thinking about licences and tidying up the code.

Any particular features you need? Either way we definitely want to allow people to customise without changing the core code.

Update 19/8/2013 - Now open source under the EPL licence https://github.com/salk31/RedQueryBuilder

Comment: I want to edit the code to create CQL query strings, no table involved. I also want to expand the logical operators to include Not and some more text based ones such as Near and wildcards. Happy to pay for a good solution and open source the result, PM me?

Comment: Hmmm. Can't see any contact details for you. You can contact me at salk31@gmail.com

Comment: You should be able to add new operators already via the JSON config. The CQL issue is similar to the question [link](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEEQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F16892724%2Faccess-to-request-structure-in-redquerybuilder&ei=INDBUbuLO8TNOPvCgZgG&usg=AFQjCNHg_pf9Y-aZRAtVgkntDCwJHJBYoA&sig2=izxCZ9HNPeSv_U3kfdLZdA&bvm=bv.47883778,d.ZWU). Do you need to store the queries? Maybe parsing the SQL to generate CQL would be best bet?